# Set the default data in ChoiceType with radio buttons

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms

Is it possible to set de default radio choice option to business? I'm using the following symfony code but none of the radio options are selected default in the form.

```
        ->add('business', 'choice', array(
            'translation_domain' => 'messages',
            'choices' => array('business' => true, 'private' => false),
            'expanded' => true,
            'multiple' => false,
            'choices_as_values' => true,
        ))
```

Comment: What version of symfony are you using ?

Comment: The Version I'm using is 2.7

Comment: If you followed the instructions of the answer by Raphaël you should verify you updated to the last release 2.7.10 as it fixes some bugs and may solve your issue.

Comment: Thanks Heah, I had version 2.7.7 and Raphaël proposal was not working, now updated to version 2.7.10 and it works!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass default data to your form:

```
// Inside a controller
$this->createForm(YourFormType::class, [
   'business' => true, // Default value for your business field
]);
```

You can also set the default value in the form builder:

```
    ->add('business', 'choice', array(
        'translation_domain' => 'messages',
        'choices' => array('business' => true, 'private' => false),
        'expanded' => true,
        'multiple' => false,
        'choices_as_values' => true,
        'data' => true, // Default value
    ))
```